# Configuring `yum` to work with automounted `/opt`

Tags: yum, centos7

`yum` software collections seem unhappy with an automounted `/opt` on CentOS 7.  How do I tell `yum` not to try installing material there?

I'm starting with a fresh CentOS 7 install – newly-installed with the standard ‘KDE Plasma Workspaces’ group, plus the NIS and automount configuration appropriate to our local network, which includes automounting `/opt`.  I try `yum update`, but that fails with

```
Transaction check error:
  installing package scl-utils-20130529-17.el7_1.x86_64 needs 4KB on the /opt filesystem
```

The problem appears to be that `yum` believes there is no space in the `/opt` tree.  The OS does appear to concur:

```
# df /opt
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
auto.opt               0     0         0    - /opt
```

But that's simply because the automounter is sitting there.  I did notice that the CentOS install included an empty `/opt/rh`.  I therefore (slightly reluctantly) added an `/opt/rh` automounted read-write from localhost, so there's actually plenty of space there:

```
# df /opt/rh
Filesystem              1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-home 426967356 33016 426934340   1% /opt/rh
```

That produced the same error.  If `yum` insists on putting things in `/opt/rh`, then it should at least test that directory, rather than simply `/opt` (which is what I suspect is happening here).

In the [software collections documentation](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/#sect-The_Software_Collection_Root_Directory) I note that that one can change the location of this ‘root directory’ from `/opt/`*provider*, but this appears to refer to creating a metapackage rather than installing one; the same manual's [‘Advanced Topics’ notes on ‘Using Software Collections over NFS’](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/Packaging_Guide/chap-Advanced_Topics.html#sect-Using_Software_Collections_over_NFS) also seem to refer to the process of building an .rpm for oneself.  The scl(1) program promises to set up such software, but is clearly not intended to fix this issue.

The documentation on yum.conf(5) doesn't mention any parameters which seem relevant (searching for `root` and `/opt`).  The [FHS discussion of `/opt`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#optAddonApplicationSoftwarePackages) isn't particularly clear, but is consistent with `/opt` being mounted read-only, and this is consistent with the [notes mentioned above](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/Packaging_Guide/chap-Advanced_Topics.html#sect-Using_Software_Collections_over_NFS) saying that ‘This enables you to mount the /opt file system hierarchy over NFS as read-only’ (though I can see that might be approaching the problem from the slightly different point of view of doing the `yum` install to `/opt` on the NFS server).  The ‘yum+CentOS7 isn't working for me’ questions here seem to be focused on repositories rather than install locations.

I'll mention in passing that I did *not* expect a package manager to be attempting to write to `/opt`.  But I thought: ‘no problem, I *must* be able to tell it not to do that...’

It's been more than a decade since I last used an RPM-based distribution in earnest, so I may be a little rusty on the conceptual framework; I'm doing this semi-experimentally to see if CentOS can be a happy citizen in our current rather heterogeneous network.

Comment: You're trying to install Software Collections, which always install under `/opt`. No regular package will install there. A more pertinent question would be: Why are you automounting `/opt`?

Comment: Setting diskspacecheck to 0 in yum.conf may be a workaround.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I wasn't quite _planning_ to install Software Collections, but they seem to have come along for the ride, with the yum update (it looks like the update is trying to install `scl-utils` rather than a specific collection). The docs suggest that the metapackage can ask to be installed elsewhere, so that's at least a known configuration. And I'm automounting `/opt` in order to serve optional/third-party software to NFS clients. `yum` appears to be assuming that `/opt/rh` exists, it's writable, and that the space on `/opt/rh` is the same as the space on `/opt`, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @MarkWagner Thanks – that worked perfectly! Interestingly, nothing ended up installed in `/opt/rh` after the update, so it seems the check was otiose as well as mis-conceived.

Comment: I've submitted a [CentOS bug report](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=10301). @MarkWagner Since I believe this is a bug rather than normal operation, a workaround counts as an Answer; if you were inclined to expand your comment into an answer with a tiny bit more context, I'd be very happy to mark it as accepted.